# Uploaded videos are not playing in mobile browser but are playing on desktop broswer

Tags: video, mobile, browser, nginx, video-streaming

I have set up a server (gunicorn and nginx) to upload videos using Python/Django, and watch them in the browser. The video player I am using is videojs. All the videos are h.264 mp4. And the video size are between 5-40 MB.

The video uploads fine and I can watch the uploaded video on the desktop and laptop browser too.

The problem is that I can't watch the same videos (which are playing on the desktop browser) on the mobile devices.

I get this error:

> This video could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.

What is wrong?

**Update**

However I tested the mobile browsers with webm videos in the mobile and Opera and Chrome plays the video perfectly. This is the command I used for webm:

```
ffmpeg -i test2.mov -codec:v libvpx -quality good -cpu-used 0 -b:v 600k -maxrate 600k -bufsize 1200k -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -vf scale=-1:480 -threads 4 -codec:a vorbis -b:a 128k -strict -2 test2_webmmm.webm
```

And this for h.264 mp4 (only working firefox):

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.avi -codec:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -preset slow -b:v 250k -maxrate 250k -bufsize 500k -vf scale=-1:360 -threads 0 -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 96k output.mp4
```

**Update**

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'faststart.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.100
  Duration: 00:03:36.56, start: 0.046440, bitrate: 350 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yu
v420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 249 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.9
5 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt
p, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

**Update**

Here are some points that I gathered along the way:

1. Some of the videos which I downloaded from YouTube and uploaded it on the server without encoding are playing nicely on all the browsers.
2. However if I encode the same video (YouTube video) and upload it on the server, it does not play on the mobile devices but only on desktop browsers.
3. Videos which I took from my mobile (Samsung s4 and iPhone 6), and encode it with ffmpeg are not playing on the mobile browsers, only on desktop browsers.
4. But, the URL of the same videos (which I took from mobile) which are hosted on Amazon s3 are playing nicely on all the browsers (even the non encoded videos).

Comment: H.264 baseline + AAC?

Comment: @Anatoly Yes. I used this command `ffmpeg -i inputfile.avi -codec:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -preset slow -b:v 250k -maxrate 250k -bufsize 500k -vf scale=-1:360 -threads 0 -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 96k output.mp4`. Although, there's one thing, the video's are playing nicely in firefox mobile browser but not on android chrom and ios safari.

Comment: Can you provide a link to one of the videos?

Comment: @Robin can you copy-paste the result of *ffprobe output.mp4* please?

Comment: @Mick Yes, you can find it in here http://54.169.222.113/video/62/

Comment: @Anatoly Yes, I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Please try to re encode with moov atom relocation and upload to test please

Comment: @Anatoly I am sorry I didn't get you. I am very new at this, will you please elaborate a bit more. Thank you.

Comment: @Robin - I believe Anatoly is referring to a technique commonly called 'faststart' for mp4 videos. mp4 videos typically store the meta data in a block (or 'atom') at the end of the file which makes streaming hard as it has to read the full file to get to this data. Faststart moves this 'atom' to the start of the file. More info here: http://multimedia.cx/eggs/improving-qt-faststart/

Comment: @Mick I thought `-movflags +faststart` was the solution for that.

Comment: @Robin - yes, that does the same thing (Anatoly covers both in his main answer) - I guess we have comments in several places you you may have already tried this or covered more options in offline chat?

Comment: @Mick Yes. We have covered that portion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What official documentation [tells](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC):

**Streaming and AAC Player Compatibility**

> By default when encoding AAC files using libfdk_aac the metadata
>   ('moov' atom) is written after the audio stream ('mdat' atom) at the
>   end of the file. In order to enable streaming of the encoded file the
>   'moov' atom has to be moved before the 'mdat' atom. In addition some
>   AAC player implementations have issues decoding such files.

FFmpeg offers the option '-movflags +faststart' covering that functionality which can be used during encoding:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a libfdk_aac -movflags +faststart output.m4a
```

Existing m4a files can be modified with the "qt-faststart' program which is distributed with FFmpeg in the 'tools' directory

```
qt-faststart input.m4a output.m4a
```

So you can try this:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.avi -codec:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -preset slow -b:v 250k -maxrate 250k -bufsize 500k -vf scale=-1:360 -threads 0 -codec:a libfdk_aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: I will test it out and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: I just tested the commands you gave me to try, but its still the same. Is it working on yours?

Comment: Ok, let's do this: you upload AVI original and I try to convert with different options

Comment: Actual I am coverting from mov and mp4 files, will that suffice?

Comment: I have uploaded some videos, but they are from youtube and it works fine (which I didn't encode). Secondly, even the video from videojs works fine (I  didn't encode). And lastly in the video section I added another video player with the video (which was not playing on the mobile) from s3 and it plays fine.

Comment: OK, the problem could just be with wrong MIME type on the web server 54.169.222.113

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84123/discussion-between-robin-and-anatoly).

Comment: I replied you in chat

Comment: I can't see your reply, only mine 6 hrs ago.

Comment: Ok, do you have an app binds to port 8081? If so it is recommended to serve static context directly via Nginx to user. In case of controlled access use X-Accel-Redirect

Comment: my django app server (`gunicorn`) was binded to 8001

Comment: @Robin ok, video files served directly which is good! Have we investigated and solved the problem or anything else left?

Comment: I solved my problem by doing two pass encoding. In the 2nd pass I used `qtfaststart` and its working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the video itself and it appears fine, and if downloaded to the desktop and opened with Chrome or Safari on a Mac will play fine.

It also plays from the Web using the link you provided above (54.169.222.113/video/62 ) fine on Chrome on a Mac but not on Safari. It will also play from the web link on and Android Tablet (Samsung Note) in the default browser and in Chrome.

The video itself plays fine from the desktop on Safri though. Doing this bypasses your site including your script and HTML and the video.js player.

Checking the videojs.com site they are using the same version of video.js (4.12.11) as you but when you look at the source theirs appears to have a different number of lines, which should not really be the case with the same version number. It may well be that they have simply added in some dev changes to test, but i think it would be worth revisiting your HTML and video.js set up again and try to match it as closely as possible to the videojs.com site (which I think you used as your starting point as it is close but not quite the same at the moment).

**UPDATE**

Ok - I downloaded the video from your link exactly as you provided it above, 1437658474_37_faststart.mp4, and added it as a simple static file in a local web server here.

The video played fine in the following clients which connected to the server over the network:

- Mac Safari
- Mac Chrome
- Android standard and chrome browsers
- iPhone safari

I also edited the videos.com page (locally using browser tools) and added your video and it would **not** play.

It appears that there is a subtle issue with your video on certain browsers which manifests itself when using videojs - the problem can be demonstrated quite easily using your site:

- The video never plays back on Safari on a MAC
- The video always plays back on Chrome on a MAC

Unless you have managed to solve the issue offline somehow (if so please let us know as this is an interesting problem!), I think it would be worth raising it on the videojs forums.

Comment: the video as is http://54.169.222.113/media/uploaded_files/1437658474_37_faststart.mp4 still doesn't playback on mobile

Comment: @Anatoly - Strange, thats not what I am seeing. I just played 54.169.222.113/video/62/ on a Samsung Note 10 using the default browser and it played back fine. Are you maybe using an iOS device?

Comment: @Mick Oh, is it. Then I will get the exact code from video js and try it once and will tell you.

Comment: @Mick I do have iOS device witch should support that kind of container with streams: h.264 and AAC

Comment: @Mick I changed the video player like you asked, but its still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by doing two pass encoding with `qtfaststart` (python). At first I was using `-movflags +faststart`, and no idea why it didn't work. But now its working in almost all the browsers.

This is the code I used:

1st pass

```
ffmpeg -i mobile.mp4 -codec:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -preset slow -b:v 250k -maxrate 250k -bufsize 500k -vf scale=-1:360 -threads 0 -codec:a libfdk_aac -movflags +faststart mobile-output.mp4
```

2nd pass

```
qtfaststart mobile-output.mp4 qt-mobile-output.mp4
```